# Issue with pouch.transformation during replication

Tags: javascript, encryption, couchdb, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I am currently involved in developing hybrid mobile applications using PouchDB (client-side) and CouchDB (server-side) for data storage. Everything was working quite smoothly until I decided to implement security on data stored in PouchDB. For that I am using **transform-pouch** with which I am encrypting data in the incoming method and decrypting data in outgoing method.

Below is the used code snippet.

```
 var transformFunctions = {
     incoming: function(doc) {
         Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(field) {
             if (field !== '_id' && field !== '_rev' && field !== '_revisions') {
                 if (service.isJsonObject(doc[field])) {
                     doc[field] = CipherService.encrypt(JSON.stringify(doc[field]), "password");
                 } else {
                     doc[field] = CipherService.encrypt(doc[field], "password");
                 }
             }
         });
         return doc;
     },
     outgoing: function(doc) {
         Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(field) {
             if (field !== '_id' && field !== '_rev' && field !== '_revisions') {
                 var decData = CipherService.decrypt(doc[field], "password");
                 if (service.isJsonString(decData)) {
                     doc[field] = JSON.parse(decData);
                 } else {
                     doc[field] = decData;
                 }
             }
         });
         return doc;
     }
 };

 service.commonDB.transform(transformFunctions);
```

Now the problem I am facing particularly arises in live replication, in the outgoing function it is getting already decrypted data. I have already defined changed event of PouchDB.

```
 localChanges = service.localDB.changes({
            since: 'now',
            live: 'true',
            include_docs: true
        }).on('change', function(change) {
            var docData = change.doc;
            if (!change.deleted) {
                if (docData.endUser) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("endUser", docData);
                } else {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast(docData._id, docData);
                }
            } else {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('delete', docData._id);
                });
            }
        }).on('paused', function(info) {            
            console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
        }).on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Due to that I am getting an error in the outgoing function during decryption.I am not able to understand how outgoing function is getting an already decrypted doc.

So is there any issue of transform-pouch with live replication? Has anyone faced similar issues?

I have already tried this with single time replication (Single-shot) on application start and it's working fine. But with live replication it is creating problem.

see the below debug call stack
[image]

I have debugged and identified that the yellow highlighted function is passing already decrypted data to outgoing function.

So may be it has problem with live replication or PouchDB data change event.

Anyone out there to the rescue?

Comment: Where you able to solve this. I have facing similar issue in live replication. I am syncing with Cloudant and get response {"error":"bad_request","reason":"Referer header must match host."}

Comment: @SagarMody  : yes, it was not transform issue it was my decryption code issue.